# csshX not working on Mac OS Big Sur

Tags: macos

csshX not working on Mac Big Sur. Trying to use it lead to this error:

```
Unimplemented: POSIX::tmpnam(): use File::Temp instead at /System/Library/Perl/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level/POSIX.pm line 185.
Unimplemented: POSIX::tmpnam() at /usr/local/bin/csshX line 1130.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/bin/csshX line 1130.
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Have you verified it is compatible with Big Sur? As macOS 11.0.1 is brand new it is quite possible that this (and lots of other software) won't work on the new version of macOS.

Comment: You should provide more info about how you installed this SW.  Did you manually install it from source, or use Homebew or MacPorts?  The errors above some from underlying Perl code.  I'd start with something like `sudo cpan install POSIX` to try to upgrade your Posix.pm file. Very worst case, edit that POSIX.pm file to call File::Temp at the line indicated, although editing files in `/System` is very hard, might even be nearly impossible/impractical now.

Comment: Hello Steve, Hello jimtut thank you very much for you help. I think that csshX it's not compatible with macOS 11.0.1. I have install it via homebrew - brew install csshX. The installation was successful, but whenever I tried to use csshX the mentioned error above appeared. I have tried with sudo cpan install POSIX, but the situation is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have FIXED IT!

The whole thing was that Apple used in MacOS Catalina perl 5, version 18, subversion 4 (v5.18.4) as a default, but in Big Sur perl 5, version 28, subversion 2 (v5.28.2)

csshX is not compatible with 5.28 so the easiest way is to change the default one by this command:

`defaults write com.apple.versioner.perl Version -string 5.18`

since Apple kept the previous versions:

```
sh-3.2# ls -l /usr/bin/perl*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  140176 Jan  1  2020 /usr/bin/perl
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  139184 Jan  1  2020 /usr/bin/perl5.18
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  121472 Jan  1  2020 /usr/bin/perl5.28
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  121472 Jan  1  2020 /usr/bin/perl5.30
```

and Voilà - csshX is working again!

Comment: Apple seems to have removed these old versions in Ventura, it just has 5.30 and 5.34. Any idea how to work around the problem now?

Answer (score 9):

You can also just edit /usr/local/bin/csshX with the editor of your choice and replace the first line
#!/usr/bin/perl
with
#!/usr/bin/perl5.18

Comment: This worked to open all windows, although I had all my windows tiled prior to Big Sur but with this its not tiled. I Closed the whole group of windows and it crashed, and now Terminal wont re-open. Guess there may be more issues!

Answer (score 0):

I like to fix it this way:

change

```
use POSIX qw(tmpnam);
```

to

```
use File::Temp qw/ :POSIX /;
```

From https://github.com/brockgr/csshx/issues/103

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in the fork at https://github.com/parera10/csshx

(Found under comment by dounokouno at https://github.com/brockgr/csshx/issues/103 and tested to confirm.)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1125743)